# What's the best way to handle "too many open files"?

Tags: go, concurrency, parallel-processing

I'm building a crawler that takes a URL, extracts links from it, and visits each one of them to a certain depth; making a tree of paths on a specific site.

The way I implemented parallelism for this crawler is that I visit each new found URL as soon as it's found like this:

```
func main() {
    link := "https://example.com"

    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    wg.Add(1)

    q := make(chan string)
    go deduplicate(q, wg)
    q <- link
    wg.Wait()
}

func deduplicate(ch chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for link := range ch {
        // seen is a global variable that holds all seen URLs
        if seen[link] {
            wg.Done()
            continue
        }
        seen[link] = true
        go crawl(link, ch, wg)
    }
}

func crawl(link string, q chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    // handle the link and create a variable "links" containing the links found inside the page
    wg.Add(len(links))
    for _, l := range links {
        q <- l}
    }
}
```

This works fine for relatively small sites, but when I run it on a large one with a lot of link everywhere, I start getting one of these two errors on some requests: `socket: too many open files` and `no such host` (the host is indeed there).

What's the best way to handle this? Should I check for these errors and pause execution when I get them for some time until the other requests are finished? Or specify a maximum number of possible requests at a certain time? (which makes more sense to me but not sure how to code up exactly)

Comment: You are facing a problem related to the limit of opened files per user that is controlled by operating system. If you are using Linux/Unix you can probably increase limit using ulimit -n 4096 command. This command has a threshold and it can't set whichever
the number of opened files you want. So if you want to push it further then you need to modify /etc/security/limits.conf file and set hard and a soft limit.

Comment: Also, you are starting a goroutine for each link you enconuter and if there;s to many of them at certain point defeats the purpose of goroutines and actually takes longer to do the task. You should try  having a fixed number of goroutines to do the processing and read from a channel instead of starting a new one for each link. Take a look at https://blog.golang.org/pipelines

Comment: Or maybe a pattern like: https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools? (BTW, your `WaitGroup` usage is quite odd. Add 1 for each goroutine, and defer `Done` from within each goroutine. Anything else is asking for bugs)

Comment: The best way to handle it depends on what you want to do. This is a design decision, not a technical problem.

Answer (score 2):

The files being referred to in the error `socket: too many open files` includes Threads and sockets (the http requests to load the web pages being scraped). 
See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32325343/go-tcp-too-many-open-files-debug).

The DNS query also most likely fails due being unable to create a file, however the error that is reported is `no such host`.

The problem can be fixed in two ways:

```
1) Increase the maximum number of open file handles
2) Limit the maximum number of concurrent `crawl` calls
```

1) Is the simplest solution, but might not be ideal as it only postpones the problem until you find a website that has more links that the new limit . For linux use can set this limit with `ulimit -n`.

2) Is more a problem of design. We need to limit the number of http requests that can be made concurrently. I have modified the code a little. The most important change is maxGoRoutines. With every scraping call that starts a value is inserted into the channel. Once the channel is full the next call will block until a value is removed from the channel. A value is removed from the channel every time a scraping call finishes.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    link := "https://example.com"

    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    wg.Add(1)

    q := make(chan string)
    go deduplicate(q, wg)
    q <- link
    fmt.Println("waiting")
    wg.Wait()
}

//This is the maximum number of concurrent scraping calls running
var MaxCount = 100
var maxGoRoutines = make(chan struct{}, MaxCount)

func deduplicate(ch chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    seen := make(map[string]bool)
    for link := range ch {
        // seen is a global variable that holds all seen URLs
        if seen[link] {
            wg.Done()
            continue
        }
        seen[link] = true
        wg.Add(1)
        go crawl(link, ch, wg)
    }
}

func crawl(link string, q chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    //This allows us to know when all the requests are done, so that we can quit
    defer wg.Done()

    links := doCrawl(link)

    for _, l := range links {
        q <- l
    }
}

func doCrawl(link string) []string {
    //This limits the maximum number of concurrent scraping requests
    maxGoRoutines <- struct{}{}
    defer func() { <-maxGoRoutines }()

    // handle the link and create a variable "links" containing the links found inside the page
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    return []string{link + "a", link + "b"}
}
```