# Getting too many open files during load test with gin gonic

Tags: go

To do a simulated load test have setup a very basic REST api in Go gin-gonic framework with the below code and after around 1000+ requests getting error

> http: Accept error: accept tcp [::]:8123: accept4: too many open
>   files;  retrying in 1s

```
func main() {
    gin.SetMode(gin.DebugMode)
    router := gin.Default()

    router.GET("/dummyRequest", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Data(http.StatusOK, "application/json; charset=utf-8", []byte(`{"name": "test", "age": 99}`))
    })

    router.Run(":8123")
}
```

Based on this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32325343/go-tcp-too-many-open-files-debug/38657328) I understand that this can be fixed by executing the `ulimit` command, but this will only be delaying the issue.

When I execute the `netstat -tc` command I see that new connections are made and continue to be in `ESTABLISHED` state long after the request is served.

As expected when I checked the /proc/$PID/limits as expected the below entry is seen:

```
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files
```

Please help me what other options I could try to fix this the right way.

I am using curl requests to send requests to test out the above.

Comment: Increasing `ulimit -n` to the 10K-60K range is an extremely routine setup for this sort of test, and for running in production.

Answer (score 3):

Go’s http package doesn’t specify request timeouts by default. You should always include a timeout in your service. What if a client doesn't close their session? Your process will keep alive old sessions hitting ulimits. A bad actor could intentionally open thousands of sessions, DOSing your server.

Try something like this:

```
srv := &http.Server{
    Addr:           ":8123",
    Handler:        router,
    ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
}
srv.ListenAndServe()
```

You can validate before and after by monitoring files opened by your process:

```
lsof -p [PID_ID]
```

For reference:
https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#custom-http-configuration